# Why follow-the-coin?

Tags: consensus

Why does Tezos use a follow-the-coin strategy for the random selection of bakers? Couldn't the following simpler procedure be used? Take the total owned stake `t`, sort delegates by their stake, draw a random number between `0` and `t`, and see where this number falls in the sorted list of delegates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *follow-the-coin* strategy is described in the [Tezos white paper](https://tezos.com/static/white_paper-2dc8c02267a8fb86bd67a108199441bf.pdf) (in section `3.2.4`) and is an adaptation of the [*follow-the-satoshi*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/452.pdf) algorithm developed by [Bentov & al](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~iddo/).

In essence the reason is a security question with regard to how difficult it is for an attacker to assign herself more baking rights than average. Here is an excerpt from the motivation section

> Motivation This procedure is functionally different from merely drawing a
>   random address weighted by balance.
>
> Indeed, in a secretive fork, a miner could attempt to control the generation
>   of the random seed and to assign itself signing and minting rights by creating
>   the appropriate addresses ahead of time. This is much harder to achieve if rolls
>   are randomly selected, as the secretive fork cannot fake ownership of certain
>   rolls and must thus try to preimage the hash function applied to the seed to
>   assign itself signing and minting rights.